# Ignore certain values when computing AVERAGE()

Tags: google-sheets, average

I use `AVERAGE()` in part of a formula where I `VLOOKUP` the values from another sheet.

I want to cover the case where the lookup has no match. I do not want to set it to 0, I just want to ignore it in the average calculation.

I've thought about it for some days now, and can't come up with something elegant:

```
AVERAGE(
  VLOOKUP(TEXT(today()-2,"yyyy-MM-dd"),indirect("marketHistory"&A6&"!$A$1:$F"),6,false),
  VLOOKUP(TEXT(today()-3,"yyyy-MM-dd"),indirect("marketHistory"&A6&"!$A$1:$F"),6,false),
  VLOOKUP(TEXT(today()-4,"yyyy-MM-dd"),indirect("marketHistory"&A6&"!$A$1:$F"),6,false)
)
```

Edit:

The data `VLOOKUP` is searching:

```
2018-08-18  47999.96    47999.96    47999.96    9   28076
2018-08-19  47799.96    47799.96    47799.96    5   17915
2018-08-20  40002.78    40002.78    40002.78    3   853
```

Averaging last column, looking for 2018-08-19, 2018-08-18 and 2018-08-17. Expected: 22995,5 (average of values for 2018-08-19 and 2018-08-18).

I tried enclosing the `VLOOKUP`s with `IFERROR` like this:

```
=average(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J18,I19:J20,2,false),"error"),J13,K13)
```

but I get the error:

> Function `AVERAGE` parameter 1 expects number values. But 'error' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

If I split the whole thing up, it works.

[image]

Comment: Please add details on what data you have and what result you want to get.

Comment: Added some things.

Comment: Did you try =iferror(average(... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demo of what you may need:

[image: google sheet screenshot]

- data in `A:B`
- your input in `D2:D` — the list of values to vlookup

The key is to get filtered list from a column with values. The `filter + regex` handles the task.

The formula:
`=FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A:A),TEXTJOIN("|",1,D2:D)))` gives a list of values matching selected dates:

```
28076
17915
```

Then do any operation with returned values:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A:A),TEXTJOIN("|",1,D2:D))))`